# Splitting nav tag into four equal parts

Tags: css, html

I want to divide the nav tag into four equal parts (like squares) and add four different background images to them. Here is my code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: nav {
width:200%;
height:500px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px; //for opera
background:#f3f3f3;
border:10px solid #bbbbbb;
position:absolute;
background: #f9f9f9 url(../images/joo.jpg);
}

Comment: the above is its css code

Comment: add `display: table-cell` to your `li` items

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
float:left;

}
a
{
display:block;
width:60px;



}
.img1{
background-image:url();
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.img2{
background-image:url();
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.img3{
background-image:url();
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.img4{
background-image:url();
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="#home" class="img1" >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news" class="img2">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact" class="img3">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about" class="img4>About</a></li>
</ul>
```